# PhpStorm signature every PHP file that does not have signature

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a project and want to signature every file with date and other project information on top of every file. I have a signature set in PhpStorm but that only implies on files when I create file with in PhpStorm.

Is there a way to signature existing file with PhpStorm instead of going every single file and put signature?

Comment: Depending on what information you put there, you may be able to use the copyright plugin to do that. Not sure which date you want to put in the header of your files, and why.

Comment: Related request for adding the intention to update the file header, which differs from the configured default: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60148

Comment: @yole & Andrey As I understand the guy is asking if he can apply it (the copyright comment) to a bunch if files/whole folder at once and not manually by going trough each file one by one.

Comment: its quite simple . i have about 1500 files and they dont have signature on them .. i want to apply signature all of them at once . now i have to manually open each individual file and paste signature comment block . hope this will explain my scenario

Answer (score 0):

With the Copyright plugin you can update files in batch, here's [the instruction](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/01/managing-copyright-notices-in-phpstorm/).